# Python findall, regex, unicode

Tags: python, regex, unicode, findall

I'm trying to write a Python script that searches thru a directory tree and lists all .flac files and derives Arist, Album and Title from resp. dir/subdir/filename and write that to a file. The code works fine, until it hits a unicode character. Here's the code:

```
import os, glob, re

def scandirs(path):
    for currentFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')):
    if os.path.isdir(currentFile):
        scandirs(currentFile)
    if os.path.splitext(currentFile)[1] == ".flac":
        rpath = os.path.relpath(currentFile)
        print "**DEBUG** rpath =", rpath
        title = os.path.basename(currentFile)
        title = re.findall(u'\d\d\s(.*).flac', title, re.U)
        title = title[0].decode("utf8")
        print "**DEBUG** title =", title
        fpath = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(currentFile))
        artist = fpath[0][2:]
        print "**DEBUG** artist =", artist
        album = fpath[1]
        print "**DEBUG** album =", album
        out = "%s | %s | %s | %s\n" % (rpath, artist, album, title)
        flist = open('filelist.tmp', 'a')
        flist.write(out)
        flist.close()

scandirs('./')
```

code output:

```
**DEBUG** rpath = Thriftworks/Fader/Thriftworks - Fader - 01 180°.flac
**DEBUG** title = 180°
**DEBUG** artist = Thriftworks
**DEBUG** album = Fader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decflac.py", line 25, in <module>
    scandirs('./')
  File "decflac.py", line 7, in scandirs
    scandirs(currentFile)
  File "decflac.py", line 7, in scandirs
    scandirs(currentFile)
  File "decflac.py", line 20, in scandirs
    out = "%s | %s | %s | %s\n" % (rpath, artist, album, title)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But when tried in Python console, it is working fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> title = "Thriftworks - Fader - 01 180°.flac"
>>> title2 = "dummy"
>>> title = re.findall(u'\d\d\s(.*).flac', title, re.U)
>>> title = title[0].decode("utf8")
>>> out = "%s | %s\n" % (title2, title)
>>> print out
dummy | 180°
```

So, my questions:
1) How come the same code works in the console, but not in the script?
2) How to fix the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `glob` with file names containing Unicode characters, use a Unicode string for the pattern.  This makes `glob` return Unicode strings instead of byte strings.  Printing Unicode strings automatically encodes them in the console's encoding when output.  You will still have issues if your songs have characters not supported by the console's encoding.  In that case, write the data to a UTF-8-encoded file and view it in an editor that supports UTF-8.

```
>>> import glob
>>> for f in glob.glob('*'): print f
...
ThriftworksFaderThriftworks - Fader - 01 180░.flac
>>> for f in glob.glob(u'*'): print f
...
ThriftworksFaderThriftworks - Fader - 01 180°.flac
```

This works with `os.walk` also, and is a simpler way to do recursive searches:

```
#!python2
import os, fnmatch

def scandirs(path):
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,u'*.flac'):
                album,artist,tracktitle = f.split(u' - ')
                print 'Album: ',album
                print 'Artist:',artist
                title,track = tracktitle.split(u' ',1)
                track = track[:-5]
                print 'Track: ',track
                print 'Title: ',title

scandirs(u'.')
```

Output:

```
Album:  ThriftworksFaderThriftworks
Artist: Fader
Track:  180°
Title:  01
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. Still couldn't get it to work with prefixing glob with u, but with os.walk instead of the glob construction the script works just fine with unicode and Python2.

Answer (score 0):

Python console works with your terminal and interprets unicode encoding according to its locale.

Replace the line with the new `str.format`:

```
out = u"{} | {} | {} | {}\n".format(rpath, artist, album, title)
```

And encode to utf8 when writing to a file:

```
with open('filelist.tmp', 'a') as f:
    f.write(out.encode('utf8'))
```

or `import codecs` and do directly:

```
with codecs.open('filelist.tmp', 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

or, since utf8 is default:

```
with open('filelist.tmp', 'a') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation about the console and locale. Unfortunately the proposed code fix doesn't seem to work; when prefixing the value of 'out' with 'u' the script stops with same error. the only time i could get it to get past 'out =' is when commenting the 'title = title[0].decode("utf8")' line and not prefix 'out' with 'u'. But then the script craps out at the write statement; same error.

Comment: * i tried all three of the proposed write statements

Answer (score 0):

1. In console, your terminal settings define the encoding. Nowadays, this is mostly Unicode on unices, e.g. Linux/BSD/MacOS and Windows-1252 on Windows. In the interpreter, it defaults to the encoding of the python file, which is usually ascii (unless your code starts with a UTF Byte-Order-Mark).
2. I'm not fully sure, but maybe prefixing the string "%s | %s | %s | %s\n" with a `u` to make it a unicode string could help.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about diff between console and interpreter. Makes total sense. Unfortunately the proposed u prefix doesnt work, see my reply eumiro's post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching to Python3, which handles unicode cases as expected.
Substituted:

```
title = title[0].decode("utf8")
```

for:

```
title = title[0]
```

Didn't even needed to prefix value of 'out' with 'u' or specify encoding on write.
I love Python3.